# Form submit data to SQL DB without page reload (jQuery / PHP?) then change div content

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Currently have this form

```
<div id="subfooter">
<form name="subscribe" method="post">
<input type="email" placeholder="e-mail address">
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
</div>
```

I also have another page called "_add_subscriber.php" which has the correct information to take the $_POST Data and push it into SQL.

Also I currently have 2 forms on my page. (each with different identifiers).

Now my question is...

When the submit button of form:subscribe is hit I want to post the data hidden to that _add_subscriber.php page thus enter the data to the database. (Not refreshing page!)
I also on click want to replace the contents of the 'subfooter' Div with something like...

```
<span>thanks for subcribing</span>
```

Thus hiding the original form.

I hope this makes sense, I have look at other solution but don't totally understand how they collect data from this specific form. Though It does seem to generally be a trait that PHP + jQuery can complete all the above actions for me!

Comment: Look into [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function.

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is ajax. jQuery has a good documentation about their ajax function and its usage http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Jquery Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: Does serialize mean I have to retrieve my data using Get rather than Post?

Answer (score 0):

Setting your HTML

```
<form name="subscribe" method="post" action="_add_subscriber.php">
```

Simple Ajax function I use for form submissions.

```
$('#subfooter form').on('submit', function() {

    var $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    // $('span').show(); // etc
  }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. Do i put the Ajax function in to a .js file and include it? Then just add the normal JQuery include too? Finally those variables $form and $(this) do they need to be amended or not? I can see they are referencing my DIV already. Also how do I go about changing then content of my div to a 'thanks for subscribing' after click - so they know it has been received as such?